# Particular solutions for helmholtz vector equation $\nabla^2 \bf H +\alpha^2 H=0$

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-analysis

(Chandrasekhar and Kendall, 1957) I am considering the Helmholtz vector equation (in $\mathbb R^3$):
$$\nabla^2 \bf H+\alpha^2 H=0.$$ 
Well known solutions include,
\begin{align} \bf L&=\nabla \psi \\
\bf T&=\nabla\times (\bf a\psi)\\
\bf S&=\nabla\times\bf T/\alpha
\end{align}
where $\psi$ is a scalar function such that $\nabla^2 \psi+\alpha^2 \psi=0$.

Why are the above three solutions are the solution for Helmholtz vector equation?

PS: $\alpha =$constant and $\nabla.{\bf H}=0,\ \bf a$ is a unit vector.

Comment: What's your manifold?

Comment: I don't have proper idea of what is manifold, but I am working on three dimensional vector space $\Re^3 \rightarrow \Re^3$.

Comment: They are not independent if (e.g.) $\psi$ is zero.

Comment: So it turns out I'm working on $\Re^3$ Equipped with the Euclidean norm.

Comment: So, I'm only concerned about solution for Helmholtz vector equation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given $\nabla^2\phi+\alpha^2\phi=0$, we can multiply by constant unit vector $\bf \hat{a}$ we will get
$$\nabla^2\phi\bf\hat{a}+\alpha^2\phi\bf\hat{a}=0$$
using vector identity $\bf\nabla^2H=\nabla(\nabla.H)-\nabla\times\nabla\times H$, we have
$$\nabla(\nabla.\phi\bf\hat{a})-\nabla\times\nabla\times\phi\bf\hat{a}+\alpha^2\phi\bf\hat{a}=0$$
Now, on taking curl, we get
$$\nabla\times(\nabla(\nabla.\phi\bf\hat{a}))-\nabla\times(\nabla\times\nabla\times\phi\bf\hat{a})+\nabla\times(\alpha^2\phi\bf\hat{a})=0$$
and for some scalar function $f$, we have vector identity, $\nabla\times\nabla f=0$, here $f=\nabla.\phi\bf\hat{a}$
$$-\nabla\times\nabla\times(\nabla\times\phi\bf\hat{a})+\nabla\times\alpha^2\phi\bf\hat{a}=0$$
using vector identity again, we get
$$\nabla^2(\nabla\times\phi\bf\hat{a})+\alpha^2(\nabla\times\phi\bf\hat{a})=0$$
Now if we write $\nabla\times\phi\bf\hat{a}$ as $\bf H$, we have
$$\bf\nabla^2H+\alpha^2H=0$$
Same goes for $\bf S$.

NOTE: Solution of scalar Helmholtz equation is a subset of the solution of  Vector Helmholtz equation.